# Databinding in C# , XAML. Databound Element 1 displays but databound element 2 does not

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a small WPF application I'm working on which I have greatly simplified here to illustrate the problem I am having.

This is the code behind for the app:

```
namespace RadioRecordingMonitor
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        findStationNumber();
        findRecordingFailTop();

    }

    public void findStationNumber()
    {
        var listlength = 50;
        this.DataContext = new stationAmount() { stationAmountTextData = listlength };
    }

    public void findRecordingFailTop()
    {
        var errorlenght = 20;
        this.DataContext = new errorAmount() { errorAmountTextData = errorlenght };
    }

    public class stationAmount
    {
        public int stationAmountTextData { get; set; }
    }

    public class errorAmount
    {
        public int errorAmountTextData { get; set; }
    }

}
}
```

And below is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="RadioRecordingMonitor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Radio Recording Monitor" Width="300" Background="#ECF0EF" Height="300"
     Loaded="Window_Loaded" >
<Grid>                
    <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}" >
        <Run Text="Total stations not recording:"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding errorAmountTextData}"/>
        <Run Text=" /"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding stationAmountTextData}"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem I am having is that only one of the databound elements displays at any one time. As it is only the *errorAmountTextData* element displays and if I remove the *findRecordingFailTop();* method the stationAmountTextData element does display which tells me that my variable is being passed through to the XAML side.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning an entirely different class to the `DataContext` each time, thereby replacing it each time you assign to it.

Instead, just have one class;

```
public class Amounts
{
    public int stationAmountTextData { get; set; }
    public int errorAmountTextData { get; set; }
}
```

Then, just assign that class to your `DataContext`

```
var myAmounts = new Amounts { stationAmountTextData = 123, errorAmountTextData = 456 };
this.DataContext = myAmounts;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change the datacontext to new errorAmount(), the datacontext for the whole page changes and  will not work because errorAmountTextData is not found in errorAmount instance.

Keep both the properties in one class and set that as datacontext which should work fine..